# Problem with negative numbers in sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest feautre scoring module

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, feature-extraction, sklearn-pandas, feature-engineering

I was trying auto feature engineering and selecting, so for that, I used the Boston house price dataset available in `sklearn`.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
import pandas as pd
data = load_boston()
x = data.data
y= data.target
y = pd.DataFrame(y)
```

Then I implemented the feature transformation library on the dataset.

```
import autofeat as af
clf = af.AutoFeatRegressor()
df = clf.fit_transform(x,y)
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

After this, I implemented another function to find the score of each feature in relation to the label.

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, chi2
X_new = SelectKBest(chi2, k=20)
X_new_done = X_new.fit_transform(df,y)
dfscores = pd.DataFrame(X_new.scores_)
dfcolumns = pd.DataFrame(X_new_done.columns)
featureScores = pd.concat([dfcolumns,dfscores],axis=1)
featureScores.columns = ['Specs','Score']
print(featureScores.nlargest(10,'Score'))
```

This gave error as following.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-b0fa1556bdef> in <module>()
      1 from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, chi2
      2 X_new = SelectKBest(chi2, k=20)
----> 3 X_new_done = X_new.fit_transform(df,y)
      4 dfscores = pd.DataFrame(X_new.scores_)
      5 dfcolumns = pd.DataFrame(X_new_done.columns)

ValueError: Input X must be non-negative.
```

I had a few negative numbers in my dataset. So how can I overcome this problem?

Note:- `df` has now transformations of `y`, its only having transformations of `x`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Feature selection using scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25792012/feature-selection-using-scikit-learn)

Comment: yes even this is helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a feature with all negative values:

```
df['exp(x005)*log(x000)']
```

returns

```
0     -3630.638503
1     -2212.931477
2     -4751.790753
3     -3754.508972
4     -3395.387438
          ...
501   -2022.382877
502   -1407.856591
503   -2998.638158
504   -1973.273347
505   -1267.482741
Name: exp(x005)*log(x000), Length: 506, dtype: float64
```

---

Quoting another answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/46608239/5025009):

The error message `Input X must be non-negative` says it all: [Pearson's chi square test (goodness of fit)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test) does not apply to negative values. It's logical because the chi square test assumes frequencies distribution and a frequency can't be a negative number. Consequently, [`sklearn.feature_selection.chi2`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.chi2.html#sklearn.feature_selection.chi2) asserts the input is non-negative.

In many cases, it may be quite safe to simply shift each feature to make it all positive, or even normalize to `[0, 1]` interval as suggested by EdChum.

If data transformation is for some reason not possible (e.g. a negative value is an important factor), you should pick another statistic to score your features:

- [`sklearn.feature_selection.f_regression`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.f_regression.html#sklearn.feature_selection.f_regression) computes ANOVA f-value
- [`sklearn.feature_selection.mutual_info_classif`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.mutual_info_classif.html#sklearn.feature_selection.mutual_info_classif) computes the mutual information

Since the whole point of this procedure is to prepare the features for another method, it's not a big deal to pick anyone, the end result usually the same or very close.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and guidance.

Comment: you are welcome. consider accepting my answer if it helped

Comment: I am accepting your answer, as soon as the time limit gets over